# Which is more correct: "embodied by" or "embodied within"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expression-choice

Which of the following seems more grammatically correct to you?

> This subjectivity is **embodied by** the concept of qualia
>
> This subjectivity is **embodied within** the concept of qualia

"Embodied *within*" seems to be more commonly used, but for some reason it doesn't sound quite right to me in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.  *[Embody](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20embodied)* means either represent or make manifest an abstraction, like an idea or principle, i.e., literally to give a body, a concrete form to something:

> The team **embodies** the spirit of winning.

Or transposed into the passive

> The spirit of winning is **embodied by** the team.

Or it may mean to contain, as enclose within itself:

> The country is adapting to the changes in national health insurance policy as **embodied within** the Affordable Care Act.

Comment: The first definition most closely matches my intent (insofar as one abstract concept can "give concrete form" to another...). I suppose my question is more about the sentence structure. If *"the team embodies the spirit of winning"* then it follows that *"the spirit of winning is embodied by the team"*. However the second construction sounds a little bit unnatural to me, and I can't find many reputable examples of its use.

Comment: I suppose I will stick with option 1 then.